# ionCube Loader Error in VPS

Tags: php, centos, vps, ioncube

I am trying to install ioncube loader on my VPS running on centos 6 64 bit, but can't get it to work, not sure why the loader is disabled

```
[root@server ~]# php -v
PHP Warning:  Module 'ionCube Loader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
The ionCube PHP Loader is disabled because of startup problems.
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2017 12:27:09)
```

Inside of /usr/lib64/php/modules/usr/lib64/php/modules I only have 
ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so

Inside php.ini, also referring to the same 5.3 loader, not sure what's wrong with the config. Any help will be appreciated!

***EDIT***

I tried deleting the ioncube loader 5.3 file from modules and now I get the following

```
[root@server ~]# php -v
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Not sure why it is trying to load the same file twice.

Comment: You may have an additional php.ini directory configured that's resulting in the php.ini file being loaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add the appropriate line for your version of the ioncube/php loader in the php.ini for the php version you have the error for?

Comment: Yes, the last two lines in php ini are 

tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir = "/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl = 86400

[Ioncube]
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so

and my php version is 5.3